# Predict values of some numerical vectors by using other numerical vectors with all these vectors in the same vector set

Tags: math, linear-algebra, mathematical-optimization, predicate, pca

I need to solve a problem about predicting values of some numerical vectors by using other numerical vectors with all these vectors in the same vector set, which is generated by one or more black box functions.

Given a vector space:

```
P =[S_1, S_2, …, S_T |  Sk is a vector of q numbers, k = 1, ..., T]
```

Find a sub-group of vectors g = {S_d | d belongs to 1, …, T } and a function h( S_d )

Such that

```
       Difference between the value of h(S_g) and S_r is minimized

       set g  + set r  =  set P 

       set g and set r have no overlap
```

What kinds of knowledge I need to solve the problem ?

If the question should not be here, please tell me where it should be posted ?

---

**update:**

The question can be expressed as:

Given a set S of vectors, find a function h() whose arguments are from part of vectors of S (we call it S1). The output of h() are the vectors of another part of S (we call it S2). The output h() are the predicated values for S2. We need to keep the prediction errors minimized and the size of S1 minimal.

How to find the h() ?

Comment: math.stackexchange.com

Comment: The function `h` maps vectors to... what, real numbers? Or vectors? What is `S_r`? Are `S_g` and `S_r` members of g and r? Are we talking about the *average* difference over all possible such pairs? Does "difference" involve absolute value? If so, **what keeps h(S)=0 from being a perfect soluion?** If not, why not make h huge and negative?

Comment: Any random linear function h allows you to split the set of vectors in non-overlapping parts. Just determine the range of values over all vectors and take the median value m. Then the sets of vectors S with h(S)<m and h(S)>=m are separated by a hyperplane. I'm rather sure this is not what you want, so please clarify your task. Model reduction, PCA, factor analysis are other keywords that may be loosely associated.

Comment: @Beta, h maps to vectors. S_r is a vector from set r, S_g is a vector from set g. Difference is the absolute value of two vectors , one is from the function h(S_g) another is from S_r. What do you mean "perfect soluion" ?